# WPF ListBox automatically scrolls to first or last element when clicking on the scroll bar

Tags: wpf

I've published this opensource WPF control: [WPF-AutoComplete-Textbox](https://github.com/quicoli/WPF-AutoComplete-TextBox)
it works fine until you click in the scrollbar buttons. When you click, the control starts iterating through the list, up or down, this is not the expected behavior....
It's like the RequestBringIntoView event is triggered and never stops... I tried to debug but can't see what is wrong... someone else eyes could see what I can't see here the moment...

A vide explains much better the issue: [screen recording](https://recordit.co/CvaHzsstn2)

Any help is welcome!